# change exact values with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a small problem with findByIdAndUpdate in mongoose:

my code:

```
const editCarrito = await Carrito.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {pedido:{ cantidad: cantidad, bebidas:bebidas.toString(), rentrega: rentrega}, comentarios:{vegetariano: vegetariano.toString(),retirar: retirar, adicional: adicional}})
```

The problem:

I have this data stored in mongoDB:

[image]

saving editcarrito deletes important data such as type, name, platoid. I need that data to remain there and that is why I do not include them in order thinking that by not being there will not modify anything as happens with image or userid:

[image]

any ideas? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution :)

```
const editCarrito = await Carrito.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {$set: { 'pedido.cantidad': cantidad, 'pedido.bebidas':bebidas.toString(), 'pedido.rentrega': rentrega}})
```

the property set is the key